# Get downloadable URL(Resource URL) from DailyMotion Videos & other sites?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, download, uiwebview

I need to Download videos from online video hosting sites(i.e. YouTube, DailyMotion, vimeo etc.) to my iOS application.

Recently i am getting video URL from `UIWebView` as user try to play any video in it. And after getting resource url(url of video which saved at some online path) and try to download it.

i had done it in YouTube by below stuff:

```
NSString *resourceUrlStr ;
NSString *urlStr  = @"function getURL() { return document.getElementsByTagName('VIDEO')[0].src; } getURL();";

 resourceUrlStr = [myWebViewObject stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: urlStr];
```

This stuff only works for YouTube videos, Where resourceUrlStr provide me url of video resource.

But when i try this stuff for DailyMotion & other video hosting websites, It doesn't return me resource video url.

Any guesses? Or idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several techniques to perform it.

My prefered technique is,
When Player in WebView start playing a Video You need to set below code for notification :

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    [super viewWillAppear:YES];


   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(myVideoPlayedInFullscreenFirstTime:)
                                                 name:@"AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification"
                                               object:nil];
}


-(void)myVideoPlayedInFullscreenFirstTime:(NSNotification*)aNotification {

    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [aNotification object];
    if(playerItem == nil) return;
    // Break down the AVPlayerItem to get to the path
    AVURLAsset *asset = (AVURLAsset*)[playerItem asset];
    NSURL *downloadebaleVideoUrl = [asset URL];

/* now, You can download video by above URL.
In some cases it will give you “.m3u” file location. 
You can go through it & get All videos from that list.
For DailyMotion there is one library on GitHub:
[For DailyMotion](https://github.com/oikyn/ExtractVideoURLManager)

*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It helps me :)

Answer (score 0):

Swift version of solution suggested by #KunalParekh is:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.myVideoPlayedInFullscreenFirstTime), name: "AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification", object: nil)
}

func myVideoPlayedInFullscreenFirstTime(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    var playerItem = aNotification.object
    if playerItem == nil {
        return
    }

    let asset:AVURLAsset = playerItem?.asset as! AVURLAsset
    var downloadebaleVideoUrl = asset.URL
    print("downloadable video url is: \(downloadebaleVideoUrl)")
}
```

Do remember to import AVFoundation

Comment: Notification name should be `Notification.Name` in Swift 3.0. As a side note AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification doesn't fire in WKWebView. For UIWebView it's all good.